# Pull in analytics and click stats for goo.gl links in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, goo.gl

I've used [this guide](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76050/google-sheets-function-to-get-a-shortened-url-from-bit-ly-or-goo-gl-etc) to create a Google sheet that creates shortened goo.gl links - is there any way I can update this to show the click stats in the next column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the code below, you're able to insert the *analytics* information as well.

### Code

```
var SHORT = "short", INFO = "info", LONG = ' long';

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("Shorten")
    .addItem("Create Links !!","createShorts")
    .addItem("Get analytics !!","getInfo")
    .addItem("Get long URL", "getLong")
    .addToUi()  
}

function createShorts() {
  performAction(SHORT);
}

function getInfo() { 
  performAction(INFO);
}

function getLong() {
  performAction(LONG);
}

function performAction(action) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(), data = range.getValues();
  var output = [], url, value, index;

  for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    value = data[i][0];
    switch(action) {
      case SHORT:
        url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: value}), index = 1;
        output.push([url.id]);
        break;
      case INFO:
        url = UrlShortener.Url.get(value, {projection: 'FULL'}), index = 1;
        var a = url.analytics.allTime;
        output.push([flattenObject(a)]);        
        break;
      case LONG:
        url = UrlShortener.Url.get(value), index = 2;
        output.push([url.longUrl]);        
        break;        
    }
  }
  range.offset(0, index).setValues(output);
}

function flattenObject(obj) {
  var f = new cFlatten.Flattener();
  return f.flatten(obj);
}
```

### Explained

Continuing from the answer you used as a guide, a couple of things have changed:

- menu has another item
- code is re-used to perform both actions
- the cFlatter is used to flatten the object obtained from the *url.analytics.allTime*

Perform the same action as you would do for creating the urls, but now select the shortened urls and pick the new menu item in the *Shorten* menu.

You can change `projection: "FULL"` into:

- `"ANALYTICS_CLICKS"` - returns only click counts
- `"ANALYTICS_TOP_STRINGS"` - returns only top string counts (e.g. referrers, countries, etc)

or you can change `url.analytics.allTime` into:

- `url.analytics.month`
- `url.analytics.week`
- `url.analytics.day`
- `url.analytics.twoHours`

to alter the analytics information.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Library Key

Add the library key, of the cFlatten library, in the Script Editor under Resources > Libraries:
[image]

### References

- [Url: get](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url/get)
- [GAS library cFlatten](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/unflatten) by [Bruce McPherson](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+BruceMcpherson/posts) (MqxKdBrlw18FDd-X5zQLd7yz3TLx7pV4j)