# How to manipulate text strings in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, regex

I've found [this super userful code](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82600/pull-in-analytics-and-click-stats-for-goo-gl-links-in-google-sheets) that I have managed to add to a Google Sheet (total newbie here) but I have a couple of problems.

The first is to disregard blanks. I want to select a list, get links or stats for all URLs in the list. But if there is a single missing value in the list, it creates an error. It should be possible just to set it to disregard blank or non-conforming values and continue.

Second, for the analytics, I'm getting a return like:

> {shortUrlClicks=20, longUrlClicks=23}

so with long lists of data, almost all of it is irrelevant. I just want the value for the total number of clicks on the short link. Is it possible to just return, for example:

> 20

I've tried pasting in the [`Mid` function from here](https://gist.github.com/brucemcpherson/3358690) but using it but I just get a shower of error messages. All suggestions targeted  at idiot-level user gratefully read carefully.

Full code I'm using added:

```
var SHORT = "short", INFO = "info", LONG = ' long';

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("New Link Shortener")
    .addItem("Shorten Links","createShorts")
    .addItem("Get Analytics","getInfo")
    .addItem("Extract Long URL", "getLong")
    .addToUi()  
}

function createShorts() {
  performAction(SHORT);
}

function getInfo() { 
  performAction(INFO);
}

function getLong() {
  performAction(LONG);
}

function performAction(action) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(), data = range.getValues();
  var output = [], url, value, index;

  for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    value = data[i][0];
    switch(action) {
      case SHORT:
        url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: value}), index = -1;
        output.push([url.id]);
        break;
      case INFO:
        url = UrlShortener.Url.get(value, {projection: 'ANALYTICS_CLICKS'}), index =2;
       //var a = url.analytics.allTime;
       var a = url.analytics.week.shortUrlClicks;
       var b = ([flattenObject(a)]); 
        output.push(b);        
        break;
      case LONG:
        url = UrlShortener.Url.get(value), index = 2;
        output.push([url.longUrl]);        
        break;        
    }
  }
  range.offset(0, index).setValues(output);
}

function flattenObject(obj) {
  var f = new cFlatten.Flattener();
  return f.flatten(obj);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74892/discussion-on-question-by-william-campbell-how-to-manipulate-text-strings-in-goo).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing from

```
var a = url.analytics.week.shortUrlClicks;
   var b = ([flattenObject(a)]); 
    output.push(b);        
    break;
```

To

```
var a = url.analytics.week.shortUrlClicks;
//var b = ([flattenObject(a)]); 
Logger.log(a);
    output.push([a]);        
    break;
```

Ref:https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url#resource

Comment: Woah! Worked. Many thanks!