# How can I get a complete list of my albums in Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

I've tried the code below (provided by [muzso in 2019](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/135556/197614)) but it only returns a limited number (~30) of my hundreds of albums. Any thoughts on how to overcome this limitation?

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
var s = '';

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

  let link = links[i];

  if (/\b\d+ items\b/.test(link.innerText)) {

    let divs = link.getElementsByTagName('DIV');

    for (var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {

      let div = divs[j];
      let text = div.innerText;

      if (text != "" && div.childElementCount == 0 && ! /\b\d+ items\b/.test(text)) {
         s = s + text + '\t' + link.href + '\n';
      
        break;
      
      }

    }

  }

}

s;
```

Comment: Results through this API as well as others like Gmail's are batched.  One of the answers points out that the default is 20 and the max is 50 and you need to use tokens to get the rest.  Work from this answer https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123623 and a Google Apps Script.  The others are problematic and the coding is a bit "peculiar".