# Using Google URL Shortener API in Google Sheets for bulk URL shortening

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, url, url-shortening

Recently come across similar issue to this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76050/google-sheets-function-to-get-a-shortened-url-from-bit-ly-or-goo-gl-etc/92321#92321), where I want to add use the Google URL shortener API in Google Sheets for bulk URL shortening.

However, I keep running into this error:

> Rate Limit Exceeded (line 12, file "Code")

within the code

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("Shorten")
    .addItem("Go !!","rangeShort")
    .addToUi()  
}

function rangeShort() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(), data = range.getValues();
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: data[i][0]});
    output.push([url.id]);
  }
  range.offset(0,1).setValues(output);
}
```

so it's to do with this line

```
var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: data[i][0]});
```

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google URL Shortener service was shut down.

Answer (score 2):

The message is pretty clear: you are invoking the service too often. This is discussed in [Google URL Shortener 403 Rate Limit Exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17775593) which indicates that the acceptable rate is somewhere between 1 and 10 requests per second.

Use the method [`Utilities.sleep`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds) to slow down the requests. For example, `Utilities.sleep(1000)` within the loop will ensure a 1-second interval between calls.