# I can't get the script to show in the menu of a G Suite document

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms, google-slides

I'm new to scripting and have been trying to get this [URL shortener](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76050/google-sheets-function-to-get-a-shortened-url-from-bit-ly-or-goo-gl-etc?newreg=9a7158d3849b4d24a8f55ecbf45f2c40) script to show in my spreadsheet. I have clicked 'debug' to authenticate the script, then what?

I thought the menu item would be created in the Google Sheet... what am I missing please? I'm sure it's pretty basic!

Editor notes: The same applies to spreadsheets, documents, forms and presentations of the nowadays named by Google as G Suite document editors.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add something to a menu, you need to implement an `onOpen` function, and do the necessary menu setup there.

Take a look at this example from [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopen):

```
function onOpen() {
  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addToUi();
}
```

This will add a menu *Custom Menu* with a single item *First item*, which, when selected, will launch a function `menuItem1`, which you will have to implement:

```
function menuItem1() {
  // Do whatever you like here
}
```

Note that you will have to reload your file ( spreadsheet, document, form or presentation ) in order to have `onOpen` run. So you won't see any effect by just writing the script and clicking save, you need to reload (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>) on the file window for the new menu to appear.

A script error may prevent the menu from appearing. If you don't see the desired result after reloading the file, check the script editor's *View → Execution Transcript* for any errors.

Comment: Thanks, Vidar, I'll give that a go today! Appreciate the help greatly.